# Hash plaintext into password worthy strings

Tags: security, hash, openssl, cryptography, passwords

I want to create a way to deterministically create strong passwords. Meaning every time registering for a site, I want to remember some kind of "hint", and "hash" that "hint" into a strong password for the site. I think it'll be a good alternative to password storage apps and better security than remembering passwords.

One easy way to do this is to use `openssl`. For example:

```
echo -n "password hint for facebook" | openssl dgst -sha256
>>159cb97d048a50a9bc124d2e6795cec1f5e0850ee9f5148fbb1d4e822dd4dd9c
```

But the hash created in this way is not strong enough. i.e. It does not contain special characters. It might be fine for utility purposes but some sites will ask your password to contain at least one special character. Anyone have a better idea?

Comment: It is encoded in hex representation and 256-bit. You can choose other encodings as base64.

Comment: What is the difference between a "hint" and a password? Who supplies the hint?

Comment: I supply the "hint", the motivation behind that is that I'll be able to remember the hint much easier than a strong password. And I can have hints like "password facebook" for facebook and "password google" for google.

Comment: Have a look at [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) for ideas on passphrase generation.

Answer (score 1):

Password crackers are very aware of deterministic techniques like this, and it does not result in a more-secure password.

Passwords in public leaks using this technique are regularly cracked in bulk at high speeds. Tools like MDXfind will try thousands of different kinds of nested hash combinations, tools like John the Ripper will let you construct arbitrary dynamic combinations of nested hashes (using its dynamic hash algorithm syntax), and hashcat has a number of common nestings built in.

Also note that varying a single element of a password based on the name of the site is also a very well-known memory technique, and password crackers use this to their advantage.

To assess the security of your proposed method, you have to imagine how it would be weakened if the attacker knew exactly what your method was. If your method is in any way weaker after being disclosed, it is insufficient. This is known as [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

In this case, if the only thing that varies in your password is the site name, then once it is cracked on *any* site, the attacker will instantly recognize the pattern and be able to reconstruct your password for *all* sites. It should be immediately obvious why this is bad.

You are much better off using a password manager, protected with two-factor authentication and a randomly generated passphrase, and then generating truly random passwords for all of your other accounts. That way you only really have to remember one password, so you can make it strong (say, six words drawn at random from a 20,000-word dictionary).

Comment: I'm not exactly trying create *more* secure passwords, I just need it to be not *less* secure. Of course someone with brute force hashing abilities will be able to crack this password, but they would be able to crack any other password I type in by hand as well. Beside that, mdxfind is for mdx algorithms, and its vulnerabilities has been publicly addressed. On top of that I never mentioned anything about wanting to hide this method, so it's not relatable to Kerckhoff's Principle.

Comment: You said you're looking for a way to deterministically create strong passwords. I've explained why this is not only infeasible, but also demonstrably less secure. Strong passwords that are type-able are quite possible - random passphrases. MDXfind is for far more than just MD5-based algorithms; it can crack many other nested/multi-layered algorithms as well, including what you've proposed. And since your method is one that attackers can predict and leverage across other sites, your proposal is objectively less secure in the aggregate, which is *exactly* what Kerckhoff's Principle predicts.